# HBase rowkey design for column family desc order sorting

Tags: hbase, row-key

I am wondering whether I can design a rowkey in a hbase table in a way that the stored data will be DESC sorted following a column family data.
Otherwise, is there any way to store data in a DESC ORDER following a specific column family?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is way to sort column or column family, Hbase stores data sorted based on row key.

so why don't you put your column as part of row key. and then scan API has the way to do reverse scan. which might help you.

Comment: Thank you, I am also thinking that way, I will give it a try thank you !